# Visual studio 2010 with sql server 2008 (default with vs10) and sql 2012. How can I choose from 2008 or 2012 while adding database in server explorer?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, server-explorer

I have **Visual studio 2010**, **sql server 2008 R2** and **sql server 2012 express** installed in my **windows 8** pc.

When I create any database project in **vs2010** it **uses** the **sql sever 2012** (Using server Explorer window).

I want to **change this behavior** and want to choose 2008 or 2012 server as per my need.

Is it possible??

*I don't have Sql server Management Studio.*

Answer (score 0):

After the project is created:

1. Open the database project's properties.
2. Go to the Project Settings tab.
3. Change "Target platform" to SQL Server 2008 or whichever option you need.

Comment: I am currently working on a WCF Service application , when I go to project settings(2) It shows nothing.

It want's me to create a settings for that...but I have no clue about that..

Any idea about that?

Comment: Did you try this for the database project's properties? If so, are there any settings in the Project Settings tab?